# OS X 10.7 Lion removed functions EmptyRect and SectRect, what are replacements?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, deprecated

I am compiling old Apple example code for OS X Lion. Code is using functions EmptyRect and SectRect. Lion API diff tells me they are removed. What functions I'm supposed to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the rectangles manually, like this:

```
Rect myRect = { left, top, right, bottom }; // Same as SetRect (left, top, right, bottom);
if ((myRect.right <= myRect.left) || (myRect.bottom <= myRect.top)) // Same as EmptyRect (myRect)
{
    //... do something
}
```

The thing is that these methods are deprecated because QuickDraw and other parts of Carbon may no longer exist in Lion. So you may run into more problems and more things missing as you try to build this example. I recommend finding a newer example that does the same thing or something similar.

Comment: I thought they are simple functions and just needed corresponding implementations. Thanks!